# Error in sending data to cloud server and arduino lagging

Tags: arduino, iot

The code im working on, is suppose to show temperature, humidity and able to take and show heart rate on the lcd. After data is shown, it will send data to "ThingSpeak". After sending, there will be a http code error -401 which is ok as it can only send data very 15 sec. But after awhile, it will change it error http code -301... and then it will hang. Another issue is when i try to use the temperature sensor with the heart rate sensor, the lcd will hang and it will not work till i reset.

```
    #include "ThingSpeak.h"
    #include "SPI.h"
    #include "DHT.h"
    #include <Ethernet.h>
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
    LiquidCrystal lcd(10, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2); //numbers of interface pins
    #define redLED 8
    int sensorPin = A8;
    float tempC;

    #define DHTPIN 6
    #define DHTTYPE DHT11
    DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
    float h;

    #define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS true    // Set-up low-level interrupts for most acurate BPM math.
    #include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>     // Includes the PulseSensorPlayground Library.   

    //  Variables
    const int PulseWire = A9;       // PulseSensor PURPLE WIRE connected to ANALOG PIN 0
    const int blinkPin = 22;          // The on-board Arduino LED, close to PIN 13.
    int Threshold = 550;           // Determine which Signal to "count as a beat" and which to ignore.

    PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;  // Creates an instance of the PulseSensorPlayground object called "pulseSensor"


    byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x10, 0x40, 0x4F};
    unsigned long myChannelNumber = ;
    const char * myWriteAPIKey = "";

    // Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
    IPAddress ip(172, 17, 171, 199);
    IPAddress myDns(172, 17, 171, 254);

    float get_temperature(int pin)
    {
      float temperature = analogRead(pin); // Calculate the temperature based on the reading and send that value back
      float voltage = temperature * 5.0;
      voltage = voltage / 1024.0;
      return ((voltage - 0.5) * 100);
    }

    EthernetClient client;

    void setup()
    {
      lcd.begin(16, 2);
      pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
      pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire);
      pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(blinkPin);       //auto-magically blink Arduino's LED with heartbeat.
      pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);
      pulseSensor.begin();
      dht.begin();
      Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino Ethernet hardware
      Serial.begin(9600);  //Initialize serial
      // start the Ethernet connection:
      Serial.println("Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:");
      if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0)
      {
        Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
        // Check for Ethernet hardware present
        if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware)
        {
          Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
          while (true)
          {
            delay(10); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
          }
        }
        if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF)
        {
          Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
        }
        // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
        Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, myDns);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print("  DHCP assigned IP ");
        Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
      }
      // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
      delay(1000);

      ThingSpeak.begin(client);  // Initialize ThingSpeak
    }

    void loop()
    {
      h = dht.readHumidity();
      {
        tempC = get_temperature(sensorPin);
      }

      if (tempC < 31)
      {
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(tempC);
        lcd.print(" "); //print the temp
        lcd.print((char)223); // to get ° symbol
        lcd.print("C");
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.print(h);
        lcd.print("%");
        delay(750);
      }
      else if (tempC > 31)
      {
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(tempC);
        lcd.print(" "); //print the temp
        lcd.print((char)223); // to get ° symbol
        lcd.print("C");
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.print(h);
        lcd.print("%");
        delay(750);
      }

       int myBPM = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();  // Calls function on our pulseSensor object that returns BPM as an "int".
      // "myBPM" hold this BPM value now.

      if (pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat()) 
      {   
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("BPM:");                        // Print phrase "BPM: "
        lcd.println(myBPM);                        // Print the value inside of myBPM.
        lcd.print("    ");
        delay(100);
      }

      // Write to ThingSpeak channel.
      ThingSpeak.setField(1, tempC);
      ThingSpeak.setField(2, h);
      ThingSpeak.setField(3, myBPM);

      int x = ThingSpeak.writeFields(myChannelNumber, myWriteAPIKey);
      if (x == 200)
      {
        Serial.println("Channel update successful.");

      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("Problem updating channel. HTTP error code " + String(x));
      }

    }
```